# node-gyp takes forever to execute npm/yarn commands

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, yarnpkg, node-gyp

I have a Mac recently upgraded to Big Sur and it seems like I encounter some issues with the node-gyp package upon starting new projects for example. I'd like to create a Nuxt app via `yarn create nuxt app <project-name>` and I've been stuck with this node-gyp spinning icon for more than 15 minutes now.

I've already tried to delete the yarn cache using `yarn cache clean`, doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Has somebody experienced this as well?

```
$ yarn create nuxt-app nature-emoi
yarn create v1.22.5
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[1/10] ⠂ core-js
[2/10] ⠂ @apollo/protobufjs
[1/10] ⠄ core-js
[1/10] ⡀ core-js
[2/10] ⡀ @apollo/protobufjs
[3/10] ⡀ fsevents
[4/10] ⡀ ejs
success Installed "create-nuxt-app@3.6.0" with binaries:
      - create-nuxt-app
⠠ node-gyp
create-nuxt-app v3.6.0
✨  Generating Nuxt.js project in nature-emoi
⡀ node-gyp
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by reinstalling node, which wasn't under a stable version anymore :)